# Can set be instantiated?

Tags: set, instance, treemap

I was reading about Collections, when this question stuck me.

Following is the code I wrote to test my doubt.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    TreeMap<Integer, String> tree = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
    tree.put(1, "1");
    tree.put(2, "2");
    Set<Integer> set = tree.keySet();
    System.out.println(set instanceof Set);
    System.out.println(set instanceof HashSet);
}
```

Result :

true
false

Above code says that my set object is a instance of Set. but Set is an Interface how can it be instantiated. I'm confused. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Set` is an interface, so no, you cannot directly instantiate it. Interfaces would be pretty useless if you couldn't have an instance of one, though! The instance returned by `tree.keySet()` is some concrete *implementation* of the `Set` interface.

Let's get super-specific, and look at [the `TreeMap#keySet()` source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/TreeMap.java.html#791):

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
    return navigableKeySet();
}
```

Okay, that doesn't tell us much. We need to drill down:

```
public NavigableSet<K> navigableKeySet() {
    KeySet<K> nks = navigableKeySet;
    return (nks != null) ? nks : (navigableKeySet = new KeySet(this));
}
```

So the concrete type returned is a `KeySet`! There's your implementation of the `Set` interface. http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/TreeMap.java.html#1021

Which explains this:

```
System.out.println(set instanceof Set); // prints true
System.out.println(set instanceof HashSet); // prints false
```

`Set` is an interface; `HashSet` is an implementation of that interface. `foo instanceof Set` will be `true` for every instance `foo` of *any* `Set` implementation. We already established that the concrete type of the object returned by `TreeMap#keySet()` is a `KeySet`, not a `HashSet`, so that explains why `set instanceof HashSet` is `false` – because `set` is a `KeySet`, so it cannot be a `HashSet`!

If that still doesn't make sense to you, [read up on `instanceof`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html):

> The `instanceof` operator compares an object to a specified type. You can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular interface.

Comment: Thanks  :) .... Only thing that is bothering me now is hw can I know if this set is ordered or not ???

Comment: By reading the API docs! http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#keySet%28%29